# Using mpi4py (or any python module) without installing

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, mpi4py

I have some parallel code I have written using `numpy` and `mpi4py` modules. Till now I was running it on my laptop but now I want to attack bigger problem sizes by using the computing clusters at my university. The trouble is that they don't have mpi4py installed. Is there anyway to use the  module by copying the necessary files to my home directory in the cluster?

- I tried some ways to install it with out root access but that didn't workout. So I am looking for a way to use the module by just copying it to the remote machine
- I access the cluster using ssh from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `pip install --user mpi4py`?

However, I think the best solution would be to just talk to the people in charge of the cluster and see if they will install it.  It seems pretty useless to have a cluster without mpi4py installed.